# $R[X]/(X)$ is isomorphic to $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$. Prove that $R[X]/(X)$ is isomorphic to $R$.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Did you mean $\, I = (X)\,?\ \ $

Comment: You can say so if that makes sense. I have no idea why it involves I..

Comment: if you want some sort of intuition, think about it like this:  What does an element of R[x] look like?  Well, $p(x) \in R[x]$ is a polynomial with coefficients in R.  So consider the element $r_0*x^n \in R[x]$.  What is this quotient ring?  Well it's the reduction of all multiples of x, in R[x], to 0.  So the element $r_0 x^n mod x \equiv r_0 0 = 0$.  So all nonconstant terms, i.e. all terms containing an x, are reduced to 0.  So all you're left with is the constant term, and that will equal R once you've considered all elements of R[x].

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ Consider the evaluation map $\,f(x)\mapsto f(0).\,$ Apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.